# How Do I Fix IDL Error Message: Missing ',' between member decls of same type(?)

Tags: c++, idl

I am getting the error message

```
Missing ',' between member decls of same type(?)
```

for the array

```
typedef float antennastate0[3];
```

However, in the C++11 Language Mapping Guide found here: https://www.omg.org/spec/CPP11/1.4/PDF that's how arrays are supposed to be written? I'm really confused why I am getting this error. The whole struct that the array is in is:

```
struct ddsServicerDynamicsData {
        ddsVector3_dbl rpos_eci;        //position relative to Earth in ECI coordinates (x, y, z) [m]
        ddsVector3_dbl rvel_eci;        //velocity relative to Earth in ECI coordinates (x_dot, y_dot, z_dot) [m/s]
        ddsVector3_dbl vrot_eci;        //rotation velocity around pricipal axes in ECI frame (phi_dot, theta_dot, psi_dot); TODO: units [rad/s] or [deg/s]
        ddsVector3_dbl arot_eci;        //angular orientation in ECI frame (phi, theta, psi); TODO: units [rad] or [deg]
        ddsVector3_dbl cgshift;         //vector from arbitrary reference point to S/C center of gravity (example: vector from base of robot arm to CG) in S/C coordinates
        typedef float antennastate0[3];         //antenna position vector (azimuth, elevation, polarization); TODO: units [rad] or [deg]
        typedef float antennastate1[3];
        typedef float armstate0[7];             //7DOF robotic arm joint angles (epsilon 0 to 6); TODO: units [rad] or [deg]
        typedef float armstate1[7];
        typedef float armstate2[7];
        typedef float armstate3[7];
};
```

Comment: Dare I ask why you're prefacing those with `typedef` ? Is it *really* your intention to declare a *type* and not an actual array ?

Comment: I want to declare an actual array but without the typedef the error message states that it is an anonymous type which is not supported by IDL anymore.